# Java KeyListener not holding boolean values as intended

Tags: java, input, keylistener

Here is my Input class:

```
private boolean[] keys = new boolean[256];
private boolean[] keys_last = new boolean[keys.length];

public Input(Window window) {
    window.getCanvas().addKeyListener(this);
}

public boolean isKey(int keyCode) {
    return keys[keyCode];
}

public boolean isKeyDown(int keyCode) {
    return keys[keyCode] && !keys_last[keyCode];
}

public boolean isKeyUp(int keyCode) {
    return !keys[keyCode] && keys_last[keyCode];
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

public void tick() {
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        keys_last[i] = keys[i];
    }

}

public boolean[] getKeys() {
    return keys;
}

public boolean[] getKeysLast() {
    return keys_last;
}
```

Then in my Window class for the time being, I am testing out inputs. My isKey(keyCode) method is working properly, but my isKeyDown() & isKeyUp() aren't working as I thought they would. I want it so that isKeyDown() be true on the first frame a button is press, and isKeyUp() is true on the first frame a button is released.

My theory is that if you press a button, its keys int[] value would be true and its keys_last int[] value would be false for that tick.

However, when for every tick I show the truth value of a specific key (say F for example) there is not a single frame that I can find that shows keys[70] and keys_last[70] with opposite values (70 is F).

Comment: So, in my 5 seconds of testing your, out-of-context, code snippet I would surmise that the `keyReleased` event is faster then your `tick` all associated loop code.  It raises the question of why it's important?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking.

Comment: Why is it important to flip the state on each tick?  Why not just monitor the pressed and released states?